# Solr query logical operator Field AND with () return empty set

Tags: solr

I need to find some rows that `field_a` is not equal to `'a'` and `field_b` is equal to `'b'`.

I tried 3 queries:

1. `(!field_a:'a' AND field_b:'b')` - gives correct results
2. `!(field_a:'a' AND field_b:'b')` - gives correct results (same as in 1)
3. `(!field_a:'a') AND (field_b:'b')` - always gives me empty set

What I am trying to do is something like **case 3** from the list above.
Anyone has some reference to the explanation?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The `NOT` operator in [Solr Query Syntax](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax#Differences_From_Lucene_Query_Parser) is `-`.

So you need to use something like

```
-field_a:a AND field_b:b
```